# <div> height 100% isn't working in Chrome

Tags: css, webkit

I'm having a problem, which already searched the internet but can not solve. I have an iframe, and inside I have a page that is loading the following CSS.

```
html, body {
position:relative;
height:100%;
} 

.c1{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    width:100%;
}

.c2{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    width:50%;
}

.cvalue{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    padding-right:3px;
    text-align:right;
}

.titulo{
    DISPLAY: inline-block;
    padding-left:5%;
}

.abaA{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:1px;
    width:100px;
    border:#000 solid 1px;
    border-bottom:0px;;
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
}

.abaA:hover {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.abaF{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:1px;
    width:100px;
    border:#000 solid 1px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    background-color:#EEE;
}

.abaF:hover {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.areaA{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border:#000 solid 1px;
    border-top:0px;
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
}

.areaF {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border:#000 solid 1px;
    border-top:0px;
    display:none;
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
}
```

And the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/csp/broker/cspxmlhttp.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/csp/broker/cspbroker.js"></script>
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/csp/cratera/sys/function.js"></script><script language="JavaScript">cspHttpServerMethod("KJnjcEnDVCs$h8WvTvpH0LQbuqWLNC_moK_PLd1scC8cNx6fZxqGz_mS6Q0_HRLRO2oUxExyIGwafKPhULXcfw--")</script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/csp/cratera/themes/default/css/style.css">
    <title>Cadastro de Empresa</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        function Salvar(){
            $CR.Submit("xiHqkWth9sV+2005/P0B5LY6k4AfsjV4hbGb3cevM8A",$("form"));
        }

        function Consultar(){
            $CR.Submit("tD3yLZP6yievtRoRMZLtjvnyw4Udr3eWUQNev/osmtg",$("form"));
        }

        function Novo(){
            $CR.ClearAll($("form"));;
            $CR.Submit("4evrj0yE4oGqBy1wKeKE+RJP0R4192anMoOcSNx5gJE",$("form"));
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="titulo">Cadastro de Empresa</div><br><hr size="1" style="margin:0px">
    <div class="c1" style="text-align:right;">
            <input id="btnCad1" name="btnCad1" onClick="Salvar();" type="button" value="Cadastrar"></input> 
            <input id="btnNov1" name="btnNov1" onClick="Novo();" type="button" value="Novo"></input>    
            <input id="btnCon1" name="btnCon1" onClick="Consultar();" type="button" value="Consultar"></input>  
    </div>
    <br>    
    <span class="abaA" id="aba.endereco.cad" onClick="mudarAba(this);">Cadastro</span>
    <span class="abaF" id="aba.endereco.ent" onClick="mudarAba(this);">Entrega</span>
    <span class="abaF" id="aba.endereco.cob" onClick="mudarAba(this);">Cobrança</span>
    <br>
    <div class="areaA" id="area.endereco.cad" style="width:100%;height:90%;">
        <br>
            <form id="form">
            <!-- ALL FORM CODE HERE -->
            </form>
    </div>
    <div class="areaF" id="area.endereco.cob" style="width:100%;height:90%;">
        <br>
            Hello!
    </div>
    <div class="areaF" id="area.endereco.cob" style="width:100%;height:90%;">
        <br>
            Hello!
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen in the settings tab (class = "abaA" and class = "abaF") I am not able to put the "height: 90%." It works in Mozilla and Internet Explorer, but in Chrome and Safari - both important to my project - it does not work. I have looked on the internet, and many people have this problem, and none of the solutions suggested worked for me.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a div before

```
<div class="areaA" id="area.endereco.cad" ...
```

So something like

```
<div>
    <br>    
    <span class="abaA" id="aba.endereco.cad" onClick="mudarAba(this);">Cadastro</span>
    <span class="abaF" id="aba.endereco.ent" onClick="mudarAba(this);">Entrega</span>
    <span class="abaF" id="aba.endereco.cob" onClick="mudarAba(this);">Cobrança</span>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="areaA" id="area.endereco.cad" style="width:100%;height:90%;">
    <br>
        <form id="form">
        <!-- ALL FORM CODE HERE -->
        </form>
</div>
```

will do the trick.
By the way you should check your code, it is far from being valid.

Comment: I honestly did not understand why this small change has made the code worked, but the code is working. When the code, so, I'll validate it right now. Thanks for all @Adam